# Windows SDK or Unity SDK for iOS/Android/Windows

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

We have a requirement to develop AR app for all three platforms (Android/iOS/Windows). We would like to know if there is a SDK available for windows 8 and above.

Please suggest should we develop the app using the sdk for all platform or is it advisable to develop the app using Unity?
If we prefer to develop the app using Unity will this work on all platforms like (iOS/Android/Windows).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is it a game or app? Have you looked into Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

Unity will help you because you develop once and it should work in the three, but it really depends on the AR library. For example, Vuforia doesn't work in Windows (only in the Unity Editor)

Comment: As per this link(https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/10/12/how-to-develop-augmented-reality-apps-with-vuforia-for-windows-10/#pVIEkxBAAqth1wCX.97) it seems like there is support for Windows